# Що означає "щолкун" і чи доречно його вживати?

Tags: значення-слів, росіянізм

Зустрів таке речення: "Не знаю, що тепер носять у поході вояки; а тоді носили ранець з укладкою, себ-то дві сорочки, двоє гультиків, рушник, пара онуч, пачка запасних набоїв, щітка, вакса, щолкун, шматок воску, шило, дратви, голки, нитки" (Микола Садовський "Спомини з російсько-турецької війни 1877 - 1878 р.").

Що означає у даному контексті слово "*щолкун*"? У СУМі мені не вдалося знайти відповідь, однак на сайті [Мисленеве дерево](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords/Sch.html) я натрапив на таке визначення: "пристрій, механізм, який при користуванні ним видає клацаючі звуки (різні автори)". Тобто, виходить, що таке слово може вживатися в українській мові? Але все ж, не зрозуміло, що воно означає у реченні, яке я навів на початку.

Comment: Швидше за все це розмовна назва якогось предмета "який при використанні видає клацаючі звуки". Наприклад шукачам скарбів відомий "щолкун", який вдягався на поводи: http://allcoins.msk.ru/konina-shhelkun/ Чи це той самий "щолкун" що у Садовського чи інший - сказати важко.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Якщо припустити, що це слово є росіянізмом (а воно ним і є), то можна знайти значення рос. слова *"щелкун"* у Google Books як `шматок дерева для розглажування ременів` у словнику військового жаргону в журналі ["Новый часовой"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?hl=uk&id=gIvwAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%22):

[image: щелкун]

Це ж можна зрозуміти з контексту уривку 3-го розділу ["Споминів з російсько-турецької війни 1877-1878"](http://library.kr.ua/elib/sadovskiy/spomyny.html) Миколи Садовського:

> Другого дня нас підняли дуже рано, хоч смотр повинен був відбуватися о дев'ятій годині, До сього смотру ми вже готувались кілька день. І ще з учорашнього вечора ремінні паси були вимащені **щолкунами** з воском. Защіпки підворонені. Мідні манєрки блищали, як скло, хоч видивляйся. Все реміння біля ранців, всі тринчики були вичорнені галанською сажою, натерті воском і **щолкуном** вилощені.

та в автобіографічному оповіданні Трохима Зіньковського ["Сидір Макарович Притика"](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=12870):

> Як приспіче було, то він і писне листика до батьків: так і так, любезні ви мої родителі, лучилась мені біда, горе, можна сказать, велике: загубив я "**щолкуна**" казенного чи пак скарбового,— треба-нада 25 карбованців виплатити, а як не сплатю — біда — під суд оддадуть і засудять ув орештанські роти — Сібер — каторжну роботу — на поселення, а то, може, й під розстріл піду! Дарма, що се дурниця, що "**щолкуна**" за які три шаги купити або й самому вистру гати не мудро — дак хіба ж там тямлять в наших справах що-небудь? І батько шле 25 карбованчиків, переляканий "**щолкуном**"! З розумом треба жити!..

Ні, це слово не бажане в українській мові, оскільки є росіянізмом та ще й жаргонізмом.